# Troubles using Facebook Connect with SharePoint 2010

Tags: facebook, sharepoint, oauth, access-token

We are getting troubles using Facebook Connect Graph API within a SharePoint Portal, We are facning problems while getting Access_token from cookie.
before, it was gotten from cookie and It did not come encripted like 'AAAD4Ta4Jx2MBANUYTxUZCAj6vgwON1SmgUZCpyYZAFDPj9eN679kaTuG7' but one week ago the code we get comes with that extrange format and it is not possible to get info of the user.

now, we have changed the way that we get access_token bye sending the encripted code to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?... but we always get a bad request.

Could you please indicate us. what have changed in this API recently, why did it use to work before and not now.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is now sending encrypted access tokens as part of their switch to SSL and Oauth2.0.  This is mentioned on their [Facebook Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/). They work just like normal tokens.  Use that token to call /me to get the users info, as you can't parse the user id from the token anymore.